# Accessing HTML this object within javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML code that uses some embedded python to create a table of results that have been extracted from an SQLlite database.  The HTML also uses bootstrap to create a table to highlight the rows when the mouse hovers of each row.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3> Suggested tools </h3>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr><th> Tool </th> <th> Function </th> </tr>
        {% for post in posts %}
       
        <tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass()"> <td>{{post.tool}} </td> <td> {{post.summary}}</td> <td> </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p id="test"> </p>
    </div>
```

When I select a particular row I want the row to change color. Using Bootcamp I know I can make this happen by changing the class property and the following code produces the desired result:

```
<tr class="table-light" onclick="this.className='success'"> <td>{{post.tool}} </td> <td> {{post.summary}}</td> <td> </tr>
```

This works well as each row is generated within the loop so the this object makes sure only the selected row has the class changed.  The problem is I have some further javascript code I want to add to the onclick event.  Is there a way of using a javascript function to access the this object so that it is used in the same way as elements in HTML?

I've tried this but as anticipated no success
HTML:

```
<tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass()"> <td>{{post.tool}} </td> <td> {{post.summary}}</td> <td> </tr> code here
```

Javascript:

```
function changeClass() {
      return "this.className= 'table-success';}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need delegation and unobtrusive non-inline code

Also your HTML is not valid. You should run the rendered page through a validator

```js
const additem = id => console.log(id);
document.querySelector(".table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("add")) {
    additem(tgt.dataset.id)
  } else {
    const row = tgt.closest("tr");
    if (row.classList.contains("table-light")) {
      row.classList.add("table-success");
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.table-success { background-color:green}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3> Suggested tools </h3>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th> Tool </th>
      <th> Function </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tool</td>
      <td>summary</td>
      <td> <button type="button" class="add" data-id="{{post.id}}">ID1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-light">
      <td>tool</td>
      <td>summary</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="test"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice.  I'm planning to refactor and eliminate as much in-line code as possible at some point.  However, I'm still relatively new to javascript and just wondering what advantages delegation brings over passing `this` to the function.  Also, as the rows of my table are generated server-side by a for loop, how is each row uniquely identified in the javascript as each row generated would be identical to the next.

Comment: Search google for delegation and there are hundreds of articles praising delegation. The main reason to not have inline event handlers is separation of markup and functionality. I also prefer to transfer as little code between server and client as possible but that is not super important in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it to the function:

```js
function changeClass(row) {
      console.log(row)}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass(this)"> <td>{{post.tool}} </td> <td> {{post.summary}}</td> <td> </tr>
<tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass(this)"> <td>{{post.tool}} </td> <td> {{post.summary}}</td> <td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not recommended to have inline event handling

Comment: It's also not recommended to have click events on table rows. But if you need to have some stuff liket hat you can also do it via onclick handlers. It's more difficult to maintain, that's right.

Comment: I strongly recommend [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66418586/295783)

Comment: I also recommend delegation, I also recommend not setting click events to table rows. But for using a simple check like this, the user can also use inline onclick events. Can't remember the last time I actively wrote inline event handlers, but they still work. And if it's easy and get's the job done, why not use it (especially if all logic is already set up)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing this with function call

```js
function changeClass(row) {
  row.className= 'table-success'
}
```

```css
.table-success{
  background-color:gray;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Suggested tools</h3>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th>Tool</th>
          <th>Function</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass(this)">
          <td>some data</td>
          <td>some data</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass(this)">
          <td>some data</td>
          <td>some data</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-light" onclick="changeClass(this)">
          <td>some data</td>
          <td>some data</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p id="test"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handling. Instead use [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66418586/295783)

Comment: true but he looks like beginner so I thought lets not change everything he is doing and let him actually test success then he can work on optimizing and other stuff

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<tr onclick="foo(this);"></tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
let foo = elem =>{
    console.log(elem.className);
}
```

Comment: this is not answering the question